# Color terminal line where command started

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

Is there any way to color the input line of the terminal under Ubuntu. My use case for this is if I run a command that outputs a large number of lines, stack traces for instance, it would be nice to be able to see where I entered the command so I can easily see where it started. The way the terminal is set up now its all black and white which makes it difficult to see where the output of the last run stops and the current output begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your .bashrc, uncomment the line "force_color_prompt=yes"